# Why can't I import React as "react"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, javascript-import

Problem described here too, but the response was not elaborative [React can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159945/react-cant-be-found)

`import React from 'react'` <- I know this statement is correct

Since "React" is a default export and not a named export, shouldn't this statement work too:

`import react from 'react'`

I know React.createElement() will be called in future, but why isn't react.createElement() correct? After all, the word "React" is just a name to refer to 'react' module.

Comment: Because js is case-sensitive. And jsx uses `React.createElement()`

Comment: react.createElement() is correct too if you import it with react, why you think its not?

Comment: @MWO read my answer. the compiler looks for `React` to compile the `JSX`

Comment: "React can't be found" error occurs, but we know conceptually default export can have any name therefore it must be correct @MWO. 
import React from 'react' is an example of default export right??

Comment: @AbhinavGupta `React` is a default export and you can import it as whatever you like. The problem occurs when the compiler wants to compile your code. The compiler will look for `React` in order to use `React.createElement` for example and if you define `React` in any other way you will face a problem with the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old versions of `react-scripts` which uses `webpack` as a bundler, you need to define a `React` object in your code where you use `JSX` because when the bundler is handling your code uses the defined `React` object to call for the nessecerary methods like `React.createElement` and everywhere else that react is needed. That is why if you remove the React import or write the name in any other fashion you will face an error

Comment: Are you referring to "React object" in this statement -> import React from 'react'.

Earlier, I worked on a react project with latest version(v16+) and currently the react-native version I am using is latest too (v0.67). I never explicitly defined a React object as var React = require('react')

Comment: @AbhinavGupta if you read the answer you will see I explicitly said `old versions`. In the newer versions, you don't need to define `React`. Also if using typescript you set `compilerOptions.jsx` to `preserve`  you don't have to define the `React` object.

Comment: How would you explain error at "import **r**eact from 'react' " in newer version?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta compiler sees that react has already been imported but when tries to use it can't find it.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta see compiler checks for `React` in the code it is  right that `react.createElement` is not wrong but the way that compiler is written is that it uses `React`

Comment: Understood. Thanks!!